# How to sign CAB file using signtool.exe?

Tags: .net, certificate, cab

1. I have 3 files
   **mycert.cer

   mycert.pvk

   mycert.spc**

Could someone please explain me - what this files should I use for?

2. I need to sign Test.cab file using signtool.exe from command line.
   But I do not understand - how to do it.
   Manual http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz(VS.80).aspx is not very good :(

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Microsoft Support Page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247257) explains exactly what you're trying to do. It is an outdated tutorial on "signcode.exe" which is similar but not equal to "signtool.exe".

If you want a simple solution, you may want to try signtool's wizard mode (execute `signtool signwizard`), e.g. explained [here](https://www.ascertia.com/helpdesk/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=14). But if command line execution is needed, check out the [examples on Microsoft's support page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa388170%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: There is very bad explanation on this support page.  
There is no good examples of usage of signtool.exe.  
PS.
I am not .Net developer.

Comment: I don't see what you mean. The link I posted explains how to sign a CAB file using the command line tool "signcode.exe" (which is now called "signtool.exe"). So what exactly is your problem with it?

Comment: Do they use exactly the same parameters?

Comment: Thank you very much!
I will try these examples.

Comment: The parameter signtool signwizard is no longer supported in the windows sdk 7.0

Comment: @Shurup: They don't seem to support the signing GUI wizard anymore. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/535430/signtool-error-invalid-command-signwizard

Answer (score 2):

I just spend about 1 hour to get working this stuff. *So I did it without certificate's password.*

Just to simplify all commands use following steps

1. Use this folder **C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin**
2. Copy to this folder your **MyApp.cab** file.
3. Create 2 files using this command without password as I did. *Ignore to input password in popup that appears.*

> makecert -r -pe -n "CN=yourcompanyaddress.com" -b 01/01/2016 -e
>   01/01/2030 -sky exchange companyCert.cer -sv companyPvk.pvk

4. After this execute another command to create PFX file

> pvk2pfx.exe -pvk companyPvk.pvk -spc companyCert.cer -pfx
>   companyPfx.pfx

So now you see in this folder **companyPfx.pfx**

5. And finally sign your CAB file like this using PFX file

> SignTool sign /f companyPfx.pfx  MyApp.cab

6. Open properties of this file and you should see that it is signed already.

I hope it will be useful.

Comment: Perfect! this signs the `.cab` file.

Comment: How can I add publisher to `ActiveXControl`? After signing cab file of my ActiveX control, IE not prompts user for installation. It asks for admin permission, I click yes. But setup is still not installed after that. Is it due to `Unknown Publisher`? Can you please guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Check this
Steps to sign a file using Signtool.exe
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/11/13/steps-to-sign-a-file-using-signtool-exe.aspx